# Nasty java.lang.NumberFormatException in struts2 ognl

Tags: java, exception, struts2, ognl

I'm getting this nasty exception, the problem is that I cannot control the get string since it's done by a 3rd party app. Apparently the number is too long to be parsed as int...

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1286579871769"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:528)
        at ognl.OgnlParserTokenManager.makeInt(OgnlParserTokenManager.java:63)
        at ognl.OgnlParserTokenManager.TokenLexicalActions(OgnlParserTokenManager.java:1624)
        at ognl.OgnlParserTokenManager.getNextToken(OgnlParserTokenManager.java:1498)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.jj_ntk(OgnlParser.java:3099)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.unaryExpression(OgnlParser.java:1079)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.multiplicativeExpression(OgnlParser.java:971)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.additiveExpression(OgnlParser.java:894)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.shiftExpression(OgnlParser.java:750)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.relationalExpression(OgnlParser.java:508)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.equalityExpression(OgnlParser.java:405)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.andExpression(OgnlParser.java:352)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.exclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:299)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.inclusiveOrExpression(OgnlParser.java:246)
        at ognl.OgnlParser.logicalAndExpression(OgnlParser.java:193)
```

struts2 snippet:

```
<package name="ajax" namespace="/ajax" extends="default">

        <default-interceptor-ref name="ajaxStack"/>

        <action name="**">
            <result>/WEB-INF/ajax/{1}.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
```

and the interceptor:

```
<interceptor-stack name="ajaxStack">                        
                <interceptor-ref name="checkSession" />
                <interceptor-ref name="checkAjax" />    
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />                                 
            </interceptor-stack>
```

`checkAjax` just makes sure the user is logged in and `checkSession` stores a session param in a `threadlocal`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What code is running to produce this? It's definitely too large for an `int`.

Comment: Where is the 1286579871769 coming from?

Comment: it's an app that generates flash plots, for each http get it appends the timestamp automatically so i cannot just remove it. its basically a bug in struts

Comment: Then you need to report it to the dev team. Without code and repro details, we can't help you.

Comment: repro details are easy. just wire the action in struts and pass a get param  ?ts=1286579871769. one of the default interceptors will vomit the exception above. i was just wondering if there's some config i can do in struts to avoid this..

Comment: Changing the type of the parameter to Long probably results in OGN using `Long.parseLong()` solving the problem.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have control over that parameter in the get string. ..

Comment: OGN infers the type, can you change the type of the getter for that value?

Comment: I find it amazing that nobody at struts mailing list could look into this bug

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with OGNL parser, it's the Integer.parseInt() method.  When we input a String to the Integer.parseInt method, it is not detected at compile time if the numeric value of the String is a number in range.  The following code will show a compile time error:

```
Integer y = new Integer(3223232320);
```

But the following will throw a runtime exception:

```
Integer y = new Integer("3223232320");
```

Comment: understand, but the parseint shouldnt even be called by struts in this case to start w/. here's an explanation by one of the creators of struts, apparently ognl only understands ints? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-386

Comment: So better convert it into String instead of Number (as in anything that is a java.lang.Number)

Comment: i dont way to control the http get params, they're inserted by a 3rd party app